# Get the filename from filepath column in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, special-characters, hiveql

I have a table containing the FILE_PATH column like below

```
FILE_PATH
\root\2010\2010-01\1234.zip
\root\2010\2010-02\2345.zip
\root\2010\2010-03\3456.zip
```

How to extract the filename from the FILE_PATH column, using SELECT query?

Answer (score 0):

I used below query to get the output.

```
select file_path,substr(file_path,-1*(locate('\\',reverse(file_path),1)-1)) from TABLE_NAME limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regexp_extract to get everything after last backslash:

```
select regexp_extract(file_path, '\\\\([^\\\\]*)$',1) from TABLE_NAME
```

Four back slashes is used to represent a single backslash because it is a special character.

Using split and size:

```
select split(file_path, '\\\\')[size(split(file_path, '\\\\'))-1] from TABLE_NAME
```

Using split and reverse:

```
select reverse(split(reverse(file_path), '\\\\')[0]) from TABLE_NAME
```